# How to prevent an Microsoft Access error message from populating when trying to close a form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, error-handling, popup

I have this form in Access with a bunch of drop down menu boxes.  If I choose a value from the List and then change my mind and leave it blank again, click close, I always get this message:

```
the data has been changed

Another User edited this record and saved the changes 
before you attempted to save your changes

Re-edit the record.
```

I have 3 different macros in the background running for

Deal type
Loan Exception Comments
Update Flags

I don't think those macros would affect anything to give that error.  But can I write something so that it catches this error message and ignores it and proceeds to close when I click close?

The main form VBA has this code:

```
Private Sub Close_Click()
 Me.FrmJobDetails.Form.Requery
 Me.subform1.Form.Requery

If Me.FrmJobDetails.Form.Dirty = True Then 'what I tried adding
 me.FrmJobDetails.Form.Dirty = False 'what I tried adding
End If
 If Me.subform1.Form.Dirty = True Then 'what I tried adding
 me.subform1.Form.Dirty = False 'what I tried adding
End If
    DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
    DoCmd.Save

    entry
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("aqrySBORequestSiteDetail"), , acReadOnly


    DoCmd.Close
    DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)

End Sub
```

In that code, with the comment "what I tried adding" is what I thought could prevent that error message from occurring.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you use macros? What exactly are those macros doing? No, I don't think you can 'catch' that warning and continue - it is not an error. Best to find out what is editing the record and modify code logic. That's what I had to do.

Comment: @June7 The macros in each Dropdown is just so that something must be selected and cannot be left blank. 

like If combo is Null Then
MessageBox: Please Fill out the deal type box
StopAllMacros
End If

Comment: But you say in your question you want to be able to leave blank and close. Your macros contradict this. Why use macros if you know and use VBA? I NEVER use macros. Prove your theory the macros don't cause issue - deactivate macros and see if you still get warning. What is `entry`? Why are you opening a query? Edit question to provide more info. `DoCmd.Save` does not save record, it is to save edited object. `Docmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` saves record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to handle the *Write Conflict* error (7787). When there's a write conflict, the first change goes through and the second one gets discarded.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    If DataErr = 7787 Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        On Error Resume Next
        With Me.Recordset
            .MovePrevious
            .MoveNext
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... to skip it:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

At the top of the Macro will skip any commands with errors.

This won't fix the cause, but it will stop popping up the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!  I found this to work on my end.  Same script, but DataErr 7878 instead.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    If DataErr = 7878 Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        On Error Resume Next
        With Me.Recordset
            .MovePrevious
            .MoveNext
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```